# stuck in login loop after uninstalling NVIDIA driver on Debian 10

Tags: debian, boot, drivers, login, nvidia

I'm still new to Linux, I've tried installing Nvidia driver, but it caused some issues with my laptop, it couldn't boot up without external monitor so I uninstalled the driver as follows `sudo ./file_name.run --uninstall`, one of the uninstallation steps was replacing the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with its backup version before the driver installation, after that I rebooted my laptop to get stuck in the login screen after providing correct username and password.
I logged in successfully from the terminal and tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge Nvidia` and searched for another solution but I'm still stuck.

Update:
I'm using both cinnamon and gnome, but cinnamon is the main environment which also the problem took place in. when I tried to switch to gnome I logged in successfully, I don't know how this happened but I hope this could help to specify the issue.